# Link two layouts in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to link my two Android layout and make the process.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



    }

    public void open(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder alb=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alb.setMessage("Are You Sure Do You Want This");
        alb.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked Yes Button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        alb.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked Yes Button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog al=alb.create();
        al.show();
    }


    public void clockwise(View view){
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanimation);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }
    public void zoom(View view){
ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.clockwise);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public void fade(View view){
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public void blink(View view){
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.blink);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public void move(View view){
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public void slide(View view){
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);
        iv.startAnimation(animation);
    }






public void next(View v){
   // setContentView(R.layout.recording);
   Intent inent = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);

  startActivity(inent);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**RecordActivity.java**

```
public class RecordActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaRecorder mr;
    Button play,record,stop;
    private String outputFile=null;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recording);

        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);

        outputFile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";
        mr=new MediaRecorder();
        mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mr.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    }


    public void Record(View v){
        try{
            mr.prepare();
            mr.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        record.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);


    }


    public void stop(View v){
        mr.stop();
        mr.release();
        mr=null;
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"AudioRecorded Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

    public void play(View v){
        MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mp.setDataSource(outputFile);
            mp.prepare();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playing Audio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.alertapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alert Dialog"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Raptor"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#da644860"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="zoom"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="clockwise"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="clockwise"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="zoom"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fade"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="fade"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blink"
        android:onClick="blink"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="move"
        android:onClick="move"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="slide"
        android:onClick="slide"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:id="@+id/button61"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recording.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="234dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:text="Android Audio Recording"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#d50c0c"
        android:layout_weight="0.01" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:onClick="Record"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="stop"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="play"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="play"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.alertapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RecordActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **stack trace**
>   04-22 14:24:09.415 4470-4470/com.example.admin.alertapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.admin.alertapplication, PID: 4470
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.alertapplication/com.example.admin.alertapplication.RecordActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at com.example.admin.alertapplication.RecordActivity.onCreate(RecordActivity.java:27)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I am using the above code to for linking the two layouts when next button was clicked **next()** function will be called after that **Unfortunately application has stopped** why it's happening can any one help me to fix this

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Comment: What do you mean by linking two layouts? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh see the stack trace edited in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in `RecordActivity` in this line
`play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);`
Because `recording.xml` doesn't contain `button3` so `play(Button)` will be `null`
Then you call `play.setEnabled(false);` => your app crash by `NullPointerException`